# How to declare array of objects or object?

Tags: typescript

Im making API call which returns array of objects when its successful or plain object with error when it fails.

I tried something like this using type and or operator between two interfaces:

```js
interface Foo {
  something: string;
}

interface Bar {
  somethingElse: string;
}

type SampleType = Foo[] | Bar;

const data: SampleType = [{ something: 'data ' }];

if (data.somethingElse) {
  // underlines somethingElse with error: Property 'somethingElse' does not exist on type 'Foo[]'.ts(2339)
}
```

But linter underlines somethingElse with error `Property 'somethingElse' does not exist on type 'Foo[]'. ts(2339)`

How should I type this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a [User-Defined Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to check if `data` is of type `Bar`.

```
function isBar(val: unknown): val is Bar {
    return (val as Bar).somethingElse !== undefined;
}
```

Full Example:

```
interface Foo {
  something: string;
}

interface Bar {
  somethingElse: string;
}

function isBar(val: unknown): val is Bar {
    return (val as Bar).somethingElse !== undefined;
}

type SampleType = Foo[] | Bar;

const data: SampleType = [{ something: 'data ' }];

if (isBar(data) && data.somethingElse) {
  throw new Error("Invalid data!")
}

if (data) {
  // data is of type Foo[] now
}
```